# Google drive permission issue while using Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

We have an application where we are using [Google drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/) for creating

- document
- spreadsheet
- slides

We have given the permission at the organization level in our Google administrative account. When I create a document its shows as `People at our organization can view and access` on top of the share button.

How ever when I create a spread sheet it initially shows as `People at our organization can view and access`, but when I close and open again its shows `Private only to me`.

I do not know why the permission is changing suddenly. I am not setting any permission while creating the document/sheet/slide. I am only calling the `gapi.client.drive.files.insert`

Answer (score 1):

When you first insert a file even if you have set the permissions at insert they aren't always saved I think I have seen a bug report on this some place I will try and find it.

> [Issue 3717:  Google drive api, upload file with shared permission](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3717)

After you insert the file,  do a patch on it, to update the permissions.  Don't use file.update use [patch](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/patch)

Code stolen from documentation:

```
/**
 * Patch a permission's role.
 *
 * @param {String} fileId ID of the file to update permission for.
 * @param {String} permissionId ID of the permission to patch.
 * @param {String} newRole The value "owner", "writer" or "reader".
 */
function patchPermission(fileId, permissionId, newRole) {
  var body = {'role': newRole};
  var request = gapi.client.drive.permissions.patch({
    'fileId': fileId,
    'permissionId': permissionId,
    'resource': body
  });
  request.execute(function(resp) {
    console.log('New Role: ' + resp.role);
  });
}
```

Comment: This assumes that the files.insert returned a files resource with the permissions so the app can grab a permissionId for permissions.patch. Given the bug (kudos for posting) and sparse documentation to confirm the behaviour, it's probably safer to assume the worst. Since he's making two calls anyway, I would probably suggest omitting permissions from the files.insert altogether and follow it up with a permissions.insert.

Comment: @pinoyyid that's what I normally do.  I have tested it over and over and it permissions just don't get inserted.  So I normally just patch after.  Yes its an extra all but I don't see any other work around